# Give an example of a function $f(x)$ which is continuous only at $x=0$ and $x=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

1. Give an example of a function $f(x)$ which is continuous only at $x=1$
2. Give an example of a function $f(x)$ which is continuous only at $x=0$ and $x=1$

Attempt

1. $f(x)=x,$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q},$ and $f(x)=2-x,$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}^{c}.$

Correct?

Please give me the example of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual example of a function only continuous at $0$ is
$$
E(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
-x & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
What can you say of $f(x)=E(x-a)$ ($a$ any real number)?

For a function that's only continuous at $0$ and $1$, consider
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
E(x)   & x<1/2 \\[4px]
E(x-1) & x\ge1/2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Then f is continuous when $x-a=-(x-a)$ i.e at $x=a$, putting $a=1$ we can get the solution of Question 1. Right?

Comment: @rama_ran Yes, but you also get a solution for 2.

Comment: What's that? I don't get this.

Comment: @rama_ran Do you mean you want a function that's only continuous at $0$ and at $1$?

Comment: Yes. .......................